# How to include parts of another html page in a current page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm looking for a way to include parts of one page into another page. The issue that comes up is that the other page has different styling than my main page. Is there a way to use the other style for some of the content and keep the old style for the already existing content?

For example: I have a navbar that I want to keep on every page, but my blog.html page has different styling than my navbar. How can I keep my navbar styling without affecting the blog.html style?

Comment: PHP: `include('xyz.html');` | Style with CSS

Answer (score 0):

Yes! you can maintain both styles in the same page. But condition is that both styles elements (tag classes and id) properties can't match each other style. you must have to custom style of the included page. This style may be inline or included like css file.

you can include css style file like this:

`<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "myStyle.css" />`

and inlcude php file:

```
include('header.html);
```

Or

```
include('abc.html);
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a stylesheet and refer to that on all the webpages you want to copy the style on. If you want to overide a part of the style, write a the new piece of code after reffering to the stylesheet.

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "myStyle.css" />
```

Comment: OP wants to include HTML elements and not CSS.

Comment: @MostafaElgayar He says he can add the HTML but there's a styling problem